# check what uses the disk space on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-11.10, amazon-web-services

I don not know what is using my disk space.

I tried `df` and `du` commands to check the system storage used they both show diff results

```
ubuntu@ip-111-121-42-198:~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  7.5G     0 100% /
udev                  289M  4.0K  289M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 119M  156K  119M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  297M     0  297M   0% /run/shm

ubuntu@ip-10-128-42-198:~$ sudo du -sh /
du: cannot access `/proc/3294/task/3294/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/3294/task/3294/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/3294/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/3294/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
1.9G    /
```

How do I check what is eating up my disk space?

Comment: Run du -h --max-depth=1 with elevated privileges, this should let you know what is using space in each directory to a depth of 1 level. You can then check lower levels from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A running process (or processes) has a file (or files) open that have been deleted.  The space occupied by those file(s) appears to `df` but doesn't appear to `du`.  You can use the `lsof` command to find which processes have which files open — or you can simply reboot, and the space occupied by the deleted files will be reclaimed.

The du command only shows the sizes of files that it can find by name. A deleted file does not exist in any directory (i.e., it has no name), so du cannot see it. The df command gives overall free space data on the entire filesystem, which is always accurate, but which will show the space occupied by deleted files that are still held open by some process.

Comment: Could you expand on that please? Why would the file be visible to one and not the other?

Comment: The `du` command only shows the sizes of files that it can find by name.  A deleted file does not exist in any directory (i.e., it has no name), so `du` cannot see it.  The `df` command gives overall free space data on the entire filesystem, which is always accurate, but which will show the space occupied by deleted files that are still held open by some process.

Comment: @Fran,thanks I got it, I had deleted a log file before stoping the server and then restarted it. this seems to have broken something. I have added your comment in answer I found it very useful :)